# \includegraphics pagebox without clipping

Tags: graphics, positioning, pdf, bounding-box

I have some PDF icons with a TrimBox different from the MediaBox. [For example](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8t1ky2r4zpcdcf8/mwe.pdf?dl=0):

```
Page size:      23.2441 x 20.6929 pts (rotated 0 degrees)
MediaBox:           0.00     0.00    23.24    20.69
CropBox:            0.00     0.00    23.24    20.69
BleedBox:           0.00     0.00    23.24    20.69
TrimBox:            0.00     4.25    21.26    20.69
ArtBox:             0.00     4.25    21.26    20.69
```

I would like to include the image in a way that uses the TrimBox for the positioning and dimensions and shows the whole contents from the MediaBox. But, since I am lazy, I want to do it without setting `bb` manually in `\includegraphics`.

What I have tried but does not work so far:

```
\includegraphics[pagebox=trimbox, clip=false]{my-picture}
```

What works but is too specific (not all the icons are the same):

```
\includegraphics[bb=0 4.25 21.26 20.69, clip=false]{my-picture}
```

**What are the ways to do it without having to trim the graphics manually in the LaTeX source?**

---

I use LuaLaTeX, so one option could be storing the icons in a font as glyphs, but some of them have shapes that get mangled in the conversion (tried [Font Custom](https://fontcustom.github.io/fontcustom/)) and one of them has two colours (yes, I know [this might not be an issue anymore](http://www.gust.org.pl/bachotex/2017-en/program#section-34)).

Comment: I'm not sure perhaps the first version you show "should" work but in any case I think that if you access the pdf file first via the epdf library you can get all the zzzBox dimensions and then construct a suitable inclusion. (search trimbox in the luatex manual)

Comment: Do you have an example of such a pdf?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Will take a look, thanks! The `<Page>:getTrimBox()` method looks like a good option.
@UlrikeFischer Indeed, but I didn't upload it because I don't know where to do it so it doesn't disappear in the future. I've just added a link to Dropbox, but I'd like to change it to something more "fixed".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following seems to work for pdflatex (I renamed your file to trimbox.pdf):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx,expl3}

\begin{document}
\fbox{\includegraphics{trimbox}}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\fbox{%
\pdfpagebox=4 ~ %force use of trimbox
\pdfximage{trimbox.pdf}
\int_set:Nn\l_tmpa_int{\pdflastximage} 
\includegraphics[viewport=
\dim_to_decimal:n{\pdfximagebbox\l_tmpa_int~1}~ % Returns lower-left x
\dim_to_decimal:n{\pdfximagebbox\l_tmpa_int~2}~ % Returns lower-left y
\dim_to_decimal:n{\pdfximagebbox\l_tmpa_int~3}~ % Returns upper-right x
\dim_to_decimal:n{\pdfximagebbox\l_tmpa_int~4}  % Returns upper-right y
]{trimbox}}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\end{document}
```

[image]

`\l_tmpa_int` is probably not needed, `\pdflastximage` seems to work too, but I found it a bit brave to access the last image in the middle of a new one.

lualatex doesn't know the command `\pdfximagbbox`, so a bit lua code can't be avoided to  get the viewport values:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx,expl3}

\begin{document}
\fbox{\includegraphics{trimbox}}
\directlua{
a = img.new({filename='trimbox.pdf',pagebox='trim'})
img.scan(a)
}
\fbox{\includegraphics[viewport=\directlua{tex.print(a.bbox[1]/ 65536)}
                                \directlua{tex.print(a.bbox[2]/ 65536)}
                                \directlua{tex.print(a.bbox[3]/ 65536)}
                                \directlua{tex.print(a.bbox[4]/ 65536)}]{trimbox}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It works, yes! From what I've tried, the pdflatex version doesn't work with the `graphicx.sty` in TL2015/2016 if the PDF isn't first included with `pagebox=cropbox` (the default). That is, if you remove the first `\includegraphics` or use a `pagebox` other than `cropbox` for the first inclusion of that image, the image is badly cropped. Using the latest `graphicx.sty` just works with both TeX Live versions.

Answer (score 1):

Using David Carlisle's recommendation of taking a look at the `epdf` library I got something that serves my needs, so I'm posting it as an answer. However, I'm willing to accept something that's more general, not lua-only or just better.

Here's a working code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{luacode}

\begin{luacode*}
function bbTrimBox(options,docname)
  tex.print("\\includegraphics")
  if options ~= "" then
    tex.print("["..options)
  end
  local doc = epdf.open(docname)
  if doc == nil then
    doc = epdf.open(docname .. ".pdf")
  end
  if doc == nil then
    tex.error("Could not find PDF file \""..docname.."\"")
    if options ~= "" then
      tex.print("]")
    end
  else
    if options ~= "" then
      tex.print(",")
    else
      tex.print("[")
    end
    local box = doc:getCatalog():getPage(1):getTrimBox()
    local bb = "bb=" .. box.x1 .. " " .. box.y1 .. " " .. box.x2 .. " " .. box.y2
    tex.print(bb)
    tex.print("]")
    -- doc:close() -- cannot call this, "attempt to call method 'close' (a nil value)"
  end
  tex.print("{"..docname.."}")
end
\end{luacode*}

\newcommand\includegraphicsbb[2][]{\directlua{bbTrimBox("#1", "#2")}}

\begin{document}
\fontsize{30}{40}\selectfont
This a test text \includegraphics[height=1em, pagebox=trimbox, clip=false]{mwe} \includegraphicsbb[height=1em]{mwe}
\end{document}
```

The output is as follows (using the [image from the question](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8t1ky2r4zpcdcf8/mwe.pdf?dl=0)):

[image: Output of the code above; first graphic is clipped, second is not]